# Umbraco TinyMCE editor - default anchor styling

Tags: .net, html, css, tinymce, umbraco

Is there a way using the TinyMCE for Umbraco [Version 4.7] to keep the inline style element of an  tag when it is changed in the editor.

We cannot use CSS as the html generated in this instance is for e-mail clients [inline styles are a necessary evil] and we are using a templating system for clients to edit emails without breaking layouts etc.

However, when changing a link from the default template, the standard  is created without the inline styles from the template - any particular way around this.

Before edit :

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://#####.##.##/default.aspx" 
style="color: #0a72ca;    text-decoration: none;">Item</a>
```

After edit:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://#####.##.##/default.aspx">Item</a>
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try placing styles in a proper area inside your edited content:

```
<style>
  .MyStyle {color: #0a72ca; text-decoration: none;}
</style>

<a target="_blank" href="http://#####.##.##/default.aspx" class="MyStyle">Item</a>
```

Comment: Alas, class elements and their associated styles will not be seen by some email clients - we have to adhere to all email clients as per contract. Thus we need the inline style kept on change.